# File = open() using date in file name error out, Python

Tags: python, datetime, file-io

I am trying to open a text file in python. In the following code:

```
import datime
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.now()
sitename = "Soil Report"
rptFolder = r"C:\Template_Outputs\Production Reports"

file = open(rptFolder + "\\" + sitename + "_" + today.strftime("%y%b%d_%H:%M:%S") + ".txt", "w")
```

I keep getting the following error:

> [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename:

I've narrowed it down the setting the date in the file name. It doesn't seem to like that (i.e. I just replaced the today.strftime("%y%b%d_%H:%M:%S") with "test" and it worked)

I've also tried to set the date as string to get it into the file name like:

```
str(today.strftime("%y%b%d_%H:%M:%S"))
```

No luck there either.

I need the time stamp in the file name because it the bigger script may be fun a few times in a short period.

is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing Windows, Windows doesn't allow files with colons (:). Try removing your colon from here:

```
str(today.strftime("%y%b%d_%H:%M:%S"))
```

and see what happens

Comment: Microsoft provides [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) regarding file names and permitted characters.

Answer (score 1):

the colons are generally not allowed in file names. replace with underscores.
Also, you might want to include either milliseconds, nanoseconds, or a random number at the end in the event you run more than one file per second.

Comment: Thanks a lot and the added suggestion. Great idea!

Answer (score 1):

Filenames on Windows can't contain a colon (`:`).